# Create an Array with Data from TD Tags

Tags: javascript, html

I want to export an HTML table into a spreadsheet that will be created by the JavaScript program.  I've considered doing this via the JQuery library but I don't know much about it nor do I think that it will be allowed in my situation.  I have seen a solution that uses XML but I don't know much about XML either.  What I intend on doing is creating a 2 dimensional array and exporting the contents of that array into Excel.  Unfortunately, I don't have control over the tagging scheme and I will have to use getElementsByTagName.  The tagging scheme is created via a reporting software.

The below code loops to the second row but it stops at the second row.  I can't figure out what I am doing wrong.  I hope that somebody will be able to explain a remedy to the error.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <table>
      <tr><td>a</td><td>1</td></tr>
      <tr><td>b</td><td>2</td></tr>
      <tr><td>c</td><td>3</td></tr>
      <tr><td>d</td><td>4</td></tr>
    </table>

    <script>

      var myNodelist = document.getElementsByTagName("td");
      var NumTD= (document.getElementsByTagName("td").length);
      var NumTR= (document.getElementsByTagName("tr").length);

      var NumCol=NumTD/NumTR;
      var array1 = [[]]; 
      var c=0;
      var r=0;

      alert("NumTD is: "+NumTD);
      for (var i=0;i<=NumTD;i++) {
        alert("On TD: "+i);

        alert(myNodelist[i].innerHTML);

        alert("r: "+r);
        alert("c: "+c); 

        array1[r][c]=myNodelist[i].innerHTML;
        alert("The array is at: "+array1[r][c]);

        if((c+1)==NumCol) {
          c=0;
        } else {
          c++;
        } 

        if(c==0) {
          r++;
        }

      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: your desired end result is a JSON array? how is the table being created? would it not make more sense to convert the raw data from before it was a table and export that? afaik copy and pasting a table from the html page into a spreadsheet manually works. Perhaps a better solution might be to look at adding a 'copy' button like zClip http://www.steamdev.com/zclip/?

Answer (score 2):

**Issue 1**: Work on your formatting. It's a lot easier to debug your own code when you indent correctly, use new lines effectively, and use descriptive variable names.

**Issue 2**: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property '0' of undefined` on line 19. You're trying to set `array1[0][0]` when `array1[0]` isn't an array. You need to make `array[0]` an array before you try to use it as one, like this:

```
if(!array1[i]){
    array1[i] = [];
}
```

This checks if your array exists. If it doesn't, then it is set to an empty array.

**Issue 3**: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of undefined` on line 24. Your loop runs from 0 to 8 and `myNodeList` only goes up to 7. Changing `for (var i=0;i<=NumTD;i++)` to `for (var i=0;i<NumTD;i++)` solves this issue by restricting the bounds of the loop.

**Issue 4**: Messing around with 3 indices (`r`, `c`, and `i`) is unnecessary and doesn't make things any easier. For one, `c` and `i` are always equal, so we can run the loop from `c = 0` to `c < numTD`.

**Issue 5**: Checking if `c + 1` is equal to the number of columns is clumsy. Instead, your second dimension should be `c % numCol`, which is just the remainder of `c` divided by `numCol`. It works perfectly here. We can also increment `r` when `c % numCol` is 0.

```
var myNodelist  =   document.getElementsByTagName("td");
var numTD       =   myNodelist.length;
var numTR       =   document.getElementsByTagName("tr").length;

var numCol  =   numTD/numTR;
var array1  =   [];

var r       =   0;

for(var c = 0; c < numTD; c++){
    array1[r]   =   array1[r] || [];

    array1[r][c % numCol]   =   myNodelist[c].innerHTML;

    if(c % numCol){
        r++;
    }
}
```

[Working example](http://jsfiddle.net/55uqwvao/)

**Issue 6**: This approach is generally a clumsy way to accomplish the task. It'd be a lot cleaner to grab each row, iterate through them, and grab the individual cells then. **Edit**: Got this is right before I saw @dc5's edit. His works just as well.

```
var rows        =   document.getElementsByTagName("tr");
var results     =   [];

for(var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++){
    var cells   =   rows[i].getElementsByTagName("td");

    results[i]  =   [];

    for(var j = 0; j < cells.length; j++){
        results[i][j]   =   cells[j].innerHTML;
    }
}
```

[Working example](http://jsfiddle.net/smqw5s5b/)

Answer (score 1):

With your current logic, you have a couple of problems:

1. array1 is initialized as `[[]]`
2. r (the row counter) is never incremented
3. Your for loop: `for (var i=0;i<=NumTD;i++)` should be `for (var i=0;i<NumTD;i++)`

The values read from the table are always updating the value at `array1[0,0]` and `array1[0,1]`

The fix - for the current logic, is to increment r when ever the column counter is reset to zero and to insert a new empty array at the new row if it doesn't already exist.

Code:

```
var myNodelist = document.getElementsByTagName("td");
var NumTD = (document.getElementsByTagName("td").length);
var NumTR = (document.getElementsByTagName("tr").length);

var NumCol = NumTD / NumTR;
var array1 = []; // <== initialize as empty array
var c = 0;
var r = 0;

for (var i = 0; i < NumTD; i++) {
    array1[r] = array1[r] || [];  // <== If array at row doesn't exist, 
                                  //     initialize it to a new array

    array1[r][c] = myNodelist[i].innerHTML;

    if ((c + 1) == NumCol) {
        c = 0;
        r++; // <== increment the row
    } else {
        c++;
    }
}
```

[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/cwfrrnn7/)

The above code could be simplified a bit by querying the table rows first, then iterating the rows, querying the child td's for each found row.

For example:

```
var rows =  document.getElementsByTagName("tr");
var rowCount = rows.length;
var r, c, cols, colCount;

var array1 = [];

for (r = 0; r < rowCount; ++r) {
    array1[r] = [];

    cols = rows[r].getElementsByTagName("td");
    colCount = cols.length;
    for(c = 0; c < colCount; ++c) {
        array1[r][c] = cols[c].innerHTML;
    }
}
```

[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/cwfrrnn7/2/)